# How to determine sublattices S of a root lattice R

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group, euclidean-lattices

Let $R$ be a root lattice of a irreducible root system $\Phi$.

Suppose $W$ is a Weyl group of $\Phi$ and $S$ is a sublattice of $R$ which is $W$-stable and satisfies $|R/S|<\infty$.
For example, let $m$ be a positive integer then $mR$ is a $W$-stable sublattice of $R$ and $|R/S| = m^{n}$, rank$R$ = $n$.
I don't know how to find all $W$-stable sublattices of a root lattice.

Are there any conclusions or references for such special $S$?

Thank you in advance.